# Get-AzureRmVirtualNetwork' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function in Azure Automation

Tags: azure

Im using Azure Automation and when I run Get-AzureRmVirtualNetwork i get an error as below. I realise it must need a module but how can you import the module in Azure Automation. Ive tried import-module and that errors too? Any ideas

Get-AzureRmVirtualNetwork : The term 'Get-AzureRmVirtualNetwork' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, 
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is

Answer (score 1):

ok I worked it out you need to go to you azure automation account in the Azure Portal, then select the modules gallery and there you can import other modules

Comment: Thank you very much for following up with your question. This saved me today.